# SwiftUI Form with Scrolling while Keyboard Displayed

Tags: forms, uiscrollview, keyboard, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Form with a field that is a TextField. I would like it when the keyboard appears for the Form to not be occluded by the keyboard AND for the field to be scrolled into view.

```
Form {
    ForEach(0..<self.fields.count) { index in
        CreateField(field: self.fields[index]) // this could be any of several input types
    }
}
.modifier(KeyboardHandler())
```

where `KeyboardHandler()` is any one of several solutions found on Stackoverflow to change the bottom padding of the Form when the keyboard appears/disappears.

When you use a Form (which displays things very nicely) you can expect at least one item in the Form to require the use of a keyboard. I mean, that's one of the reasons to use a Form: gather info from the user. So it surprises me that keyboard handling is not built into the Form in some way. Or rather, in a way that works without us having to do this. There are a number of keyboard solutions on Stackoverflow - this is a wheel that has been reinvented more times than the wheel itself.

I have looked at several of the solutions presented and most will change the bottom padding of the Form so that it is not occluded by the keyboard. None of the solutions I've found address the issue of scrolling the field into view.

Is that possible with SwiftUI? Should I write my own custom Form (I'd rather not)?

Comment: You can try reaching to the parent scroll view of the text field when the keyboard appears and tell it to scroll your text field into visible range, like described in this article: https://lostmoa.com/blog/ScrollTextFieldIntoVisibleRange/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. My hesitation though, is what if Apple changes the underpinnings of SwiftUI? Right now I can climb the display tree but maybe that will change. Be nicer if Apple just made Form work like I think most people expect it to work.

Comment: I totally agree, we have to be careful as changes come, hopefully we'll have a SwiftUI API for it in the future.